# List index out of range error in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am now building a web-scraping program with Python 3.5 and bs4. In the code below I tried to retrieve the data from two tables in the url. I succeed in the first table, but error pops out for the second one. The error is "IndexError: list index out of range" for "D.append(cells[0].find(text=True))". I have checked the list indices for "cells', which gives me 0,1,2, so should be no problem. Could anyone suggest any ideas on solving this issue?

```
import tkinter as tk

def test():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    import pandas as pd

    url_text = 'http://www.sce.hkbu.edu.hk/future-students/part-time/short-courses-regular.php?code=EGE1201'
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url_text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))
    all_tables=soup.find_all('table')
    print (all_tables)
    right_table=soup.find('table', {'class' : 'info'})

    A=[]
    B=[]
    C=[]
    for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))

    df=pd.DataFrame()
    df[""]=A
    df["EGE1201"]=C
    print(df)        


    D=[]
    E=[]
    F=[]
    right_table=soup.find('table', {'class' : 'schedule'})
    for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
        try:
            cells = row.findAll('th')
        except:
            cells = row.findAll('td')
        D.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[2].find(text=True))

    df1=pd.DataFrame()
    df[D[0]]=D[1]
    df[E[0]]=E[1]
    df[F[0]]=F[1]
    print(df1)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting this code to choose between 'th' and 'td', but it will not. It will always choose 'th' and will return an empty list when there is no 'th' in that row.

```
    try:
        cells = row.findAll('th')
    except:
        cells = row.findAll('td')
```

Instead, I would change the code to check if the list is empty and then request 'td':

```
    cells = row.findAll('th')
    if not cells:
        cells = row.findAll('td')
```

Alternatively you can shorten the code to this:

```
    cells = row.findAll('th') or row.findAll('td')
```

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please accept my answer if this is your chosen answer.

Comment: I have accepted that by clicking the vote button. Does it work?